# Save and load Raphael.js paper as/from text

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a Raphael.js paper object with various elements in it and I would like to save it's state in a database in some text format and then re-instantiate it later.  I know I can accomplish this if I simply keep a record of what I've added to it and what attributes I have set.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't Raphael just use svg? If so, you could just save and reinsert the svg content into the dom.